# Appending Text file over network Android API SDK min 19

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to Java and having a bit of difficulty appending to a text file. 
Am able to create and write to it, But if the file is present i can only overwrite it.

I was trying to utilise StandardOpenOption but this requires SDK 26 (And i am developing for Android 7 onwards) 
Meaning i cannot use the StandardOpenOption because of the Min SDK.

Is there any other way i can achieve this? 
Here is the code i am currently running, This is accessing a Windows Network path utilising hierynomus

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.hierynomus.msdtyp.AccessMask;
import com.hierynomus.msfscc.FileAttributes;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2CreateDisposition;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2CreateOptions;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2ShareAccess;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.SMBClient;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.SmbConfig;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.auth.AuthenticationContext;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.Connection;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.share.DiskShare;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.share.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class NetworkLogon {


    // connection paramsStaticLoggerBinder
    static String sambaDomain = null; // can be null

                                // Need to pass over Message (What to print) Filename, Folder. As this could be writing an Out and a Log file.
    public static void main(Context mContext, String message, String filename, String Folder) throws IOException {

        String sambaSharedPath = SharedPrefs.getserverPath(mContext);
        String sambaUsername = SharedPrefs.getsmbUser(mContext);
        String sambaPass = SharedPrefs.getsmbPass(mContext);
        String sambaIP = SharedPrefs.getserverName(mContext);

      //  String filename = "test.txt";

        SmbConfig cfg = SmbConfig.builder().build();
        SMBClient client = new SMBClient(cfg);
        Connection connection = client.connect(sambaIP);
        Session session = connection.authenticate(new AuthenticationContext(sambaUsername, sambaPass.toCharArray(), sambaDomain));
        DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(sambaSharedPath);

        // this is com.hierynomus.smbj.share.File !
        File f = null;
        int idx = filename.lastIndexOf("/");

        // if file is in folder(s), create them first
        if (idx > -1) {
            String folder = Folder+"\\"+filename.substring(0, idx);
            try {
                if (!share.folderExists(folder)) share.mkdir(folder);
            } catch (SMBApiException ex) {
                throw new IOException(ex);
            }

        }

        if (!share.fileExists(Folder+"\\"+filename)) {
            f = share.openFile(Folder+"\\"+filename,
                    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(AccessMask.GENERIC_ALL)),
                    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)),
                    SMB2ShareAccess.ALL,
                    SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_CREATE,
                    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE))
            );
        }
        if (f == null){

            f = share.openFile(Folder+"\\"+filename,
                    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(AccessMask.GENERIC_ALL)),
                    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)),
                    SMB2ShareAccess.ALL,
                    SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN_IF,
                    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE)) );

            }

        OutputStream os = f.getOutputStream();
        os.write(message.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        f.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried various methods and was unsuccessful, 
I decided to move away from using hierynomus.smbj as i was getting various errors in the class when trying to use different functions. 
and decided to use jcifs, and worked without any issues straight away.

A example of code:

```
// required imports
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.IOException;
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream;

public class NetworkLogon {



    public static void main(Context mContext, String message, String filename, String Folder) throws IOException {

        String sambaSharedPath = SharedPrefs.getserverPath(mContext);
        String sambaUsername = SharedPrefs.getsmbUser(mContext);
        String sambaPass = SharedPrefs.getsmbPass(mContext);
        String sambaIP = SharedPrefs.getserverName(mContext);
        try{

            String url = "smb://"+sambaIP+"/"+ sambaSharedPath +"/"+ Folder +"/"+ filename;
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
                    null, sambaUsername, sambaPass);
            SmbFile sfile = new SmbFile(url, auth);

            SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sfile, true);

            sfos.write((message+"\n").getBytes());
            sfos.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IOException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Explanation to the code for anyone new:

```
public static void main(Context mContext, String message, String filename, String Folder) throws IOException {
```

Context mContext, String message filename Folder are used to pass content from where its being called: An example:

```
                    String Folder ="Logs";
                    String message = timedateFormat+": Login Failed, Details are incorrect";
                    String filename = dateNow+"-AndroidHandHeld.log";
                    NetworkLogon.main(mContext, message, filename, Folder);
```

You can of course freetype:

```
NetworkLogon.main(mContext, "Yourmessage", "Somefilename", "SomeFolder");
```

The SharedPrefs part of the code, is another class to fetch stored details in SharedPreferences.

String url is putting together the Network Path, Shared Folder, Folder and Filename.

NtlmPasswordAuthentication initiates the Auth. Parameters (DOmain, Username, Password) In my code its showing Null for Domain as i currently have not finished defining domains yet.

SmbFile connects using the path + auth method.

Outputstream is setting the file and saying to append

Then the other two lines write the file out and close the file